# Undefined variable: userData , Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm joining 2 tables and then want to pass the data in blade file but its showing **Undefined variable: userData**

here is my code

```
public function show($userid){

    $userData = DB::table('users')
                ->select('users.*','locations.*')
                ->join('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->where('users.id', '=', $userid)
                ->get();


    //print_r($userData);

    return View::make('profile')->with($userData);
}
```

what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: that is not the error . fixed it but still the same.

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
return View::make('profile')->with('userData', $userData);
```

Instead of:

```
return View::make('profile')->with($userData);
```

So you will be able to use `$userData` in your `view`.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$userData = DB ::table ( 'users' )
    ->join( 'locations' , function ($join)
{
$join->on ('users.id' , '=',
'locations.id')
->where ('users.id', '=', $userid );
})
->get();
```

Comment: Why two answers and this is not the solution either, problem is something else.

Answer (score -2):

Provide the $userid (by passing through the parameter of the show() method)

Comment: Why tow answers and it's not the problem as well.